# What is the best practice for writing a multihomed TCP client in C with connection fallover?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, tcp

I have a machine with two NICs and would like to use the second NIC as a connection backup in the event that the internet connection on the primary network interface should go down. For the sake of discussion, lets assume each NIC is connected to a different network.

My code is written in C and could be tailored to maintain a list of all addresses assigned to each present network interface and then compare those addresses to those returned by getaddrinfo(). When a match is found, I could select the matched address from those returned by getaddrinfo() and use that address to create and connect my socket.

Is this the right way to handle the problem or is there a better way to perform connection fall-over to a secondary network interface?

I know that the routing system will attempt to choose the best interface for the connection, but if the interface is linked and an address is assigned, but outside connectivity is down, then the interface will surely timeout upon connection and the same interface will be chosen on each connection attempt. Somehow I must specify which interface to select in order to prevent making the same and potentially incorrect choice on every connection attempt.

Thoughts?

Thank you in advance.

--Eric

Comment: One popular approach is to use an Ethernet bonding driver and let the driver handle the failover aspects:  https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt

Comment: What if the second NIC is a WiFi adapter?

Comment: Dunno, I never tried that.  I'm guessing it wouldn't work very well, though.

Comment: My current thought is to try to connect to the server, and if it fails, try again using the other interface.  The question then becomes when is it appropriate to attempt to switch back to the wired / preferred interface.  All of this implies that I can bind the client to the desired interface and attempt a connection.

Comment: You could also just always try to keep a connection open at all times on both interfaces, and send the occasional ping-type command across each tcp socket to make sure that the server still responds.  Then the decision about which of the two sockets to actually use can be made based on who is responding more reliably.   (I like this approach more because that way your program has valid information about the usability of both connections simultaneously, and if connection A is having trouble it doesn't have to just guess/hope that connection B will work better and is worth trying to switch to)

Comment: The problem is that the getaddrinfo() API always sends the DNS request on the eth0 interface.  When the upstream link is unplugged, this causes a failure before the code that gets a new socket, binds and connects via the alternative interface.  I looked into bonding, but am not certain how to use it when the Wifi interface is on a different network than the wired interface.  Can each interface use DHCP and can bonding switch between *different* networks (active-backup) ?